# Custom tensorflow.compat.v1.metrics

Tags: python, tensorflow

I currently have my `eval_metric_ops` configured like this for the `train_and_evaluate` process:

```py
eval_metric_ops = {"mean_squared_error": tf.compat.v1.metrics.mean_squared_error(
             labels=features['image'],
             predictions= model.denoise_fn(normalize_data(features['image']), features['label'])),
                   }
```

My loss is defined like this:

```py
def meanflat(x):
  return tf.reduce_mean(x, axis=list(range(1, len(x.shape))))

loss = nn.meanflat(tf.squared_difference(noise, x_recon))
```

How can I apply `tf.squared_difference` to the `eval_metric_ops` definition?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the tf.math.squared_difference to loss argument

```
def meanflat(x):
  return tf.reduce_mean(x, axis=list(range(1, len(x.shape))))

loss = meanflat(tf.math.squared_difference(x,y))

eval_metric_ops = {'loss': loss}
```

For more details refer to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/kiransair/41a1798367da1b3640ac51d909625f6c). Thank You.